# Updating table column with other column of table based on combination of 2 columns if their values combination appearance is more than 1

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table 'list' like this

```
Unique|S_Number|New_Attr|C_Number|C_Order|A_Number
   123       101        1       -A       1       0
   124       101        1       -A       1       2
   125       101        1       -A       1       3
   127       101        1       -B       2       4
   128       101        1       -C       3       5
   129       101        1       -D       4       6
```

I have do it like this

```
Unique|S_Number|New_Attr|C_Number|C_Order|A_Number
  123       101        1       -A        1       0
  124       101        2       -A        1       2
  125       101        3       -A        1       3
  127       101        1       -B        2       4
  128       101        1       -C        3       5
  129       101        1       -D        4       6
```

means want to update New_Attr with A_Number value only when there is combination of S_Number and C_Number is greater than 1 and A_Number is greater than 0

I have created temporary table list_temp2 to insert only

```
CREATE TABLE list_temp2
(
  S_number CHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  C_number CHAR(32),
  CNT integer
);


INSERT INTO list_temp2 p2 (p2.s_number, p2.c_number, p2.cnt)
SELECT p1.S_number, p1.C_number,COUNT(*) FROM list p1
GROUP BY  p1.S_number, p1.C_number
HAVING COUNT(*)>1;
```

Inserts one row

```
  101  -A 3
```

```
SELECT p1.s_number, p1.c_number, p1.New_Attr, p1.a_number, p2.cnt FROM list p1
LEFT JOIN
list_temp2 p2 ON p1.s_number = p2.s_number
where p1.a_number>1 AND p2.cnt>1 AND p2.s_number = p1.s_number AND p2.c_number = p1.c_number;
```

Gives out 2 row(expected)

```
  101                       -A  1   2   3
  101                       -A  1   3   3
```

Now I to update list table, but I am not able to do it correctly if i do like this:

```
UPDATE list p1 SET p1.New_Attr=
(
SELECT p1.a_number FROM list p1
LEFT JOIN
list_temp2 p2 ON p1.s_number = p2.s_number
where p1.a_number>0 AND p2.cnt>1 AND p2.s_number = p1.s_number AND p2.c_number = p1.number
);
```

It is giving output too many values as Select command is giving 2 rows

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE your_table
SET New_Attr = IIF(A_Number>0 AND S_Number + C_Number > 1, A_Number, New_Attr)
```

To explain this you look at each and depending on the values of other rows this will update correctly your results. I may have not understood correctly the condition for the update but this should work like a charm if you apply your logic inside the iif.

Comment: Apologies i forgot to mention i am using oracle it does not have IFF, also only to copy A_Number when count >1 when S_NUMBER and C_Number are grouped together.

Comment: Solved as: merge into list
using list_temp2
on (list.s_number = list_temp2.s_number)
when matched then update set part_list.s_number = part_list.a_number
where list.a_number>1 AND list_temp2.cnt>1 AND list_temp2.s_number = list.s_number AND list_temp2.c_number = list.c_number;

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a filtered `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE list
    SET New_Attr = A_Number
    WHERE A_Number > 0 AND S_Number + C_Number > 1;
```